# Как вставить символ в регулярное выражение java?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Добрый день, не как не могу привести к нормальному формату распарсеные при помощи регулярного выражения

```
"^\\s(\\d){2}(\\d){2}(\\d){2}\\s{2}(\\d){6}\\s{3}$"
```

дату и время получаю в таком виде 09072016  154915 нужно получить вот в такаком 09-07-2016  15:49:15. Прочитал что можно вставлять символы в шестнадцатеричной системе в виде такого кода

`\x2D и \x3A`

но почему то не получается. 
код регулярки дополненный выражениями

`"^\\s(\\d){2}\\x2D(\\d){2}\\x2D(\\d){2}\\s{2}(\\d){2}\\x3A(\\d){2}\\x3A(\\d){2}\\s{3}$"`

```
String variableName = fileName;
                        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\s(\\d){2}\\x2D(\\d){2}\\x2D(\\d){2}\\s{2}(\\d){2}\\x3A(\\d){2}\\x3A(\\d){2}\\s{3}$"); 
                        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(variableName); 

                      while (matcher.find()) 
                      date = matcher.group();

                      System.out.println(date);
```

Так не работает.

Comment: И где тут вставляется `\x41`?

Comment: OK, а что тут должно работать? Вы проверяете регуляркой не исходную строку, а то, что должно получиться, то есть то, чего не существует? Приведите полный код что именно делается.

Comment: @PinkTux  дополнил, не совсем понял вас давайте по порядку 1) я получаю 09072016 154915 в виде строки помещаю в переменную 2) как можно добавить в эти данные эти символы  - :

Comment: Код покажите, который "*Так не работает*".

Comment: @PinkTux дополнил

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы не понимаете как работают регекспы. Метод `matcher.find()` ищет вхождения регулярного выражения по строке. Передавать ему то, что вы хотите вставить в качестве замены - неверно в принципе. Замену в найденом нужно делать совсем другим способом. Например, так:

```
// где ищем:
String s = "09072016 154915";
// что ищем:
String rx = "(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{4})\\s+(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(rx);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
StringBuffer strbuf = new StringBuffer();
while (matcher.find()) {
    // на что меняем:
    matcher.appendReplacement(strbuf, "$1-$2-$3 $4:$5:$6");
}
matcher.appendTail(strbuf);
// Result: 09-07-2016 15:49:15
System.out.println("Result: " + strbuf.toString());
```